# Query array of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a list of documents like this saved in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : "f9f44e87-4260-4699-99a6-af6b58b4fb7e",
    "address" : {},
    "lastUpdate" : "1414083484838",
    "listvalues" : {},
    "userModels" : {
        "5067" : {            
            "generated_date_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866),
            "model_id" : 5067,
            "score_id" : {
                "0" : {
                    "score_level_id" : 5267,
                    "confidence" : 0,
                    "generated_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866)
                }
            },
            "points" : 0,
            "delta_points" : 0,
            "override_model" : 0,
            "override_score" : 0,
        },
        "5079" : {
            "generated_date_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866),
            "model_id" : 5079,
            "score_id" : {
                "0" : {
                    "score_level_id" : 5292,
                    "confidence" : 0,
                    "generated_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866)
                }
            },
            "points" : 0,
            "delta_points" : 0,
            "override_model" : 0,
            "override_score" : 0,
        },
        "5080" : {
            "_class" : "com.mediresource.datatype.model.bean.Model",
            "generated_date_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866),
            "model_id" : 5080,
            "score_id" : {
                "0" : {
                    "score_level_id" : 5294,
                    "confidence" : 0,
                    "generated_timestamp" : NumberLong(1413985161866)
                }
            },
            "points" : 100,
            "delta_points" : 0,
            "override_model" : 0,
            "override_score" : 0,
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to count how many "userModels", for all _id in mongoDB, has more that 0 points. What I'm saving here is a Java HashMap defined as `UserModels<Integer, Model>`.

This is the query I was trying to use, but without success:

```
db.anonProfile.find(
   { "userModels": { $elemMatch: { "points":  { $gte: 0 } } } }
).size();
```

Any clue?

Comment: Nothing in your data is actually an "array" which will display with bracket `[]` notation. These are just sub-documents or Hash/Map structures and this is why it does not work. You have some bad code producing this. The structure is not optimal for your purposes.

Comment: May I create some cursors to go through the data?

Comment: The point here is that you don't want "Hash/Map" structures the way you have used them. This is an "anti-pattern" which makes queries difficult along with many other operations. Data is data, you should not be using data-points as the names of keys. Do you want to know how to do it properly and solve your problem?

Comment: I understand that, put the point is, this is from production environment and I cannot change it. This query is only for report purpose.

Comment: Then you are left with the horrible option of JavaScript based traversal only, which is much slower than more efficient options. I think talking to the boss and showing these comments would be more productive than giving you a bad performing answer.

Comment: How can I write correctly on MongoDB using Spring-Data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with `spring-data mongodb` like:

```
Criteria criteria=Criteria.where("userModels.points").gte(0));
Aggregration aggregration=newAggregration(unwind("userModels"),match(criteria),group("_id").count().as("param"));
```

But i can not understand why you are using the numbers under `userModels`.It is not good.Because of that i did not use the `numbers` under `userModels`.